# obj.template operator() construct does not work with xlC 11.1

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, xlc

The following piece of C++ code:

```
template <typename T>
static void execute(T& obj) {
    obj.template operator()<int>();
}
```

when compiled with IBM's xlC 11.1 results in the error message: *1540-0063 (S) The text "operator" is unexpected*. If I use a function instead of an operator, it works fine, but I do not want to rewrite a lot of library code. Is there any other way how to make the `.template operator` construct work with xlC?

Comment: Does `static_cast`ing `obj` to `int` not work?

Comment: Can't reproduce on GCC; this works fine on GCC 4.6.1.

Comment: @Mark B: No, obj's operator `()` is templated.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: And with Intel's icpc this works fine, too. That's why I'm asking about xlC :).

Comment: I don't even understand this code.  My brain just exploded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get the `.template operator` construct to work would be to submit a bug report to IBM.

This code conforms to the C++ standard. It is, in fact, the only legal way to write this code.

---

When you file the report you can use the following as evidence:

`§14.2/4` states:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after . or -> in a *postfix-expression* ... and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is
>   type-dependent ... the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template. ...

---

The first part: "`the name of a member template specialization`", applies because because `operator()<int>` is the name of a member template specialization. There is evidence for this in `§14.2/1`:

> A template specialization can be referred to by a *template-id*:

`§14.2/1` then specifies a syntax for a *template-id* which matches `operator()<int>`.

---

The second part: "`and the object expression of the _postfix-expression_ is
type-dependent`", applies because `obj` is type-dependent. `obj` is type-dependent because of  `§14.6.2.2/3`:

> An *id-expression* is type-dependent if it contains: - an *identifier* associated by name lookup with one or more declarations declared with a dependent type, ...

In this case, `obj` is associated with `T&`, which is a dependent type (because `T` is a template parameter).

---

This is only half of a definitive answer, as I have not provided references for many claims that I made. I have been at this for an hour now though, so it is probably time to stop.